# Declaring a variable in mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, variables, encryption, triggers

I have a MySQL trigger that is being used to call the rsaencrypt function to encrypt a particular value.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ssninsertencrypt BEFORE INSERT ON redcap_data
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.project_id = (SELECT ProjectID FROM redcap_encryption)
    AND new.field_name = (SELECT FieldName FROM redcap_encryption)
        THEN
            SET @PublicKey = (SELECT PublicKey FROM redcap_encryption WHERE     ProjectID = new.project_id);
            SET new.value = rsaencrypt(new.value,@PublicKey);
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This seems to be inconsistently working/not working so i'd like to insert the completed statement the trigger produces into another table so can see what is being passed to the rsaencrypt or not passed. I thought i could just do a SET @SQL () like the following

```
SET @SQL = 
(IF new.project_id = (SELECT ProjectID FROM redcap_encryption)
AND new.field_name = (SELECT FieldName FROM redcap_encryption)
    THEN
        SET @PublicKey = (SELECT PublicKey FROM redcap_encryption WHERE ProjectID = new.project_id);
        SET new.value = rsaencrypt(new.value,@PublicKey);
END IF;)
```

I get syntax errors on this and i'm unsure how best to proceed

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this a while ago but forgot to post :-

```
BEGIN
    IF new.field_name = (SELECT FieldName FROM redcap_encryption WHERE new.project_id = ProjectID)
        THEN
            SET @PublicKey = (SELECT PublicKey FROM redcap_encryption WHERE ProjectID = new.project_id);
            SET new.value = rsaencrypt(new.value,@PublicKey);
    END IF;
END$$
```